# After Java 1.6.0_27 update Heroku application does not boot in 60 seconds

Tags: java, heroku, playframework

When I rollback to a previous version using 1.6.0_20 my application boots within 60 seconds. Given the facts below how can I debug and solve the issue?

- My application is using Play 1.2.5
- In the logs I see the application connects to the PostgreSQL database. That is usually the last log before R10 error.

**--UPDATE**
I have created a Plugin and issued a fake port bind which will be closed after 10 seconds. That solved the bind problem but now I have a memory problem. Under high load may app was using 600M of memory. But now I see ~1500M and it is continuously increasing.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationRead() {
    final int port = Integer.parseInt(Play.configuration.getProperty("http.port"));

    try {
        // Create a new server socket and set to non blocking mode
        final ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        ssc.configureBlocking(false);
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(port);
        ssc.socket().bind(isa);
        Logger.info("Fake bind to port %d", port);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ssc.socket().close();
                    Logger.info("Fake port closed");
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Logger.error(ioe, "Cannot close fake port");
                }
            }
        }, 10000);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Logger.error(ioe, "Cannot open fake port");
    }

    Cache.forcedCacheImpl = RedisCacheImpl.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: Are you running database migrations when your app boots? If so, can you move those into a separate process?

Comment: No, there is nothing than required during the boot process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have switched to jdk 7. My app now boots in 40 seconds and uses 500-600MB of memory. I have informed Heroku about the issue but they didn't really care.

Comment: We're also having memory problems on heroku - is JDK 7 still solving your issues? How did you switch to 7? Thanks!

Comment: @MattHall yes JDK 7 is fine for me. In order to switch to JDK 7 put a file named system.properties in the root of your project and put java.runtime.version=1.7 in it.